# the dijkstra algorithm.. and i want to show the shortest path between to nodes

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define INFINITY 9999
#define MAX 10

void dijkstra(int G[MAX][MAX],int n,int startnode);

int main()
{
int G[MAX][MAX],i,j,n,u;
printf("Enter no. of vertices:");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("\nEnter the adjacency matrix:\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        scanf("%d",&G[i][j]);

printf("\nEnter the starting node:");
scanf("%d",&u);
dijkstra(G,n,u);

return 0;
}

 void dijkstra(int G[MAX][MAX],int n,int startnode)
  {

   int cost[MAX][MAX],distance[MAX],pred[MAX];
   int visited[MAX],count,mindistance,nextnode,i,j;

//pred[] stores the predecessor of each node
//count gives the number of nodes seen so far
//create the cost matrix
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
         if(G[i][j]==0)
             cost[i][j]=INFINITY;
         else
            cost[i][j]=G[i][j];

//initialize pred[],distance[] and visited[]
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    distance[i]=cost[startnode][i];
    pred[i]=startnode;
    visited[i]=0;
}

distance[startnode]=0;
visited[startnode]=1;
count=1;

while(count<n-1)
{
    mindistance=INFINITY;

    //nextnode gives the node at minimum distance
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(distance[i]<mindistance&&!visited[i])
        {
            mindistance=distance[i];
            nextnode=i;
        }

        //check if a better path exists through nextnode            
        visited[nextnode]=1;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            if(!visited[i])
                if(mindistance+cost[nextnode][i]<distance[i])
                {
                    distance[i]=mindistance+cost[nextnode][i];
                    pred[i]=nextnode;
                }
    count++;
}

//print the path and distance of each node
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    if(i!=startnode)
    {
        printf("\nDistance of node%d=%d",i,distance[i]);
        printf("\nPath=%d",i);

        j=i;
        do
        {
            j=pred[j];
            printf("<-%d",j);
        }while(j!=startnode);
  }
 }
```

the program is about the dijkstra's algorithm and it shows the shortest distance between source and destinatiom.A problem with this code is that it show the path the destination node name is not shown and all other nodes are shown.... for example if i want to find the shortest path between node0 to node 5... then the program shows the path 3<-4-<0 but its not shown 5<-3<-4<-0..

Comment: why not simply do `printf("%d", startnode);` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//pred[] stores the predecessor of each node
...
j=pred[j];
printf("<-%d",j);
```

I assume that the problem lies herein. As you only print the predecessor, when finally you reach the destination node, you print the predecessor and not the destination node.